# Can't get cookies from request in NestJS

Tags: nestjs

I got a backend perfectly running in NestJs.

Now I need to add some functionality using cookies. So I have installed cookie-parser, imported it to the main file with `import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'` and put in to the app with `app.use(cookieParser())`.

In the controller I have imported Request and Response from express:
`import { Request, Response } from 'express';`

The endpoint looks like this:

```
  @Get('/refresh') 
  async refreshToken(
    @Res({ passthrough: true }) response: Response,
    @Req() request: Request)
  {
    const {refreshToken} = request.cookies // refreshToken is [Object: null prototype] {}
    const userData = await this.authService.refresh(refreshToken)
    response.cookie('refreshToken', userData.refreshToken, {maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, httpOnly: true, secure: true})
    return userData
  }
```

I can put cookies to response, but the problem is that there is no cookies in request at all - it shows [Object: null prototype] {}

I was following the official setup https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/cookies

Any suggestions are much much appreciated!

Comment: How are you attempting to set the cookie(s) in the first place? If there are no cookies available it would be normal that you'd get back an empty object here. Is it just the following lines that attempt to set the `refreshToken`? If so you need to verify that the browser is actually processing this as expected and actually sending them back. Could be something wrong with the options you're passing

Comment: Thanks, Jesse! As appeared, the problem was in cars settings.

Comment: ...focking autospelling... I mean CORS settings of course )

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in CORS

I had this
`app.enableCors()`

but after I have added cors in app creation like this (with credentials: true), everything works just fine:

`const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: {credentials: true, origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL} })`

Comment: I am still facing the same issue. The above didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, angular frontend port 4200 not sending cookies to nestjs backend at 3000, although nestjs would read cookies if I accessed the api endpoint directly through the browswer. Anyway adding the credentials/withCredentials to the angular http request did the trick. So angular was preventing the cookies from being sent to nestjs, with cors enabled and cookie parser.

```
 public getLogin(): Observable<any> {
return this.httpClient.get(this.apiUrl + '/auth/login', {withCredentials: true}) as Observable<any>;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and I fixed it by adding the '{withCredentials: true}' when I sent the request the the API in the server, so the result

```js
 useEffect(() => {
     axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:3001/auth/fetchUser", {withCredentials: true}) // add withCredentials: true
         .then(response => {
             setTestData(response.data.user);
         })
         .catch(error => {
             console.error("Error fetching user failed:", error);
         });
 }, []);
```